# ASP.Net Core dependency injection | How to access user or route data upon creation

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, multi-tenant

## Scenario

I am working to follow the IoC pattern and use the Microsoft DI Framework, but I'm hitting a wall and can't decide if it's my mindset, my approach, or I'm just doing it wrong.

I have a multi-tenant application that utilizes a Utility class to handle isolation and accessing the data of the tenant based on their unique configuration. The tenant is identified during authentication, but the tenant data has to be accessible and handled based on the request. This Utility class is registered under ConfigureServices in the `Startup.cs` and the constructor requires two parameters  - a `TenantDbContext` and a `Tenant`.

```
public class TenantUtility{
     public TenantUtility(TenantDbContext context, Tenant tenant){/*...*/}
}
```

## Problem

Realizing that I'm probably pushing the limits of the DI Framework, I'm trying to build an implementationFactory in the `Startup.cs`. I've tried two approaches for accessing the tenant Id to build the `Tenant` object: one is using a User Claim, the second is a Route parameter.

```
services.AddTransient<TenantUtility>((svc)=> {
   var tenantContext = svc.GetService<TenantDbContext>();
   var accessor = svc.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
   var httpContext = accessor.HttpContext;

    //httpContext is NULL...
    //How do I get access to the tenant?
    Common.Tenant t = new Common.Tenant();
    //Set Tenant Identifier in t (once I get it)
    return new StudentDataManager(tenantContext, t);
});
```

In both situations, when I setup the ImplementationFactory inside the Startup.cs, I don't have access to the user and I don't have access to the RouteData (or can't figure out how to get it) -- I even tried using `IHttpContextAccessor`, but the `HttpContext` property is null.

Am I approaching the pattern incorrectly? Should I be able to use DI for this level of detail be injected into the Utility before the Utility class is passed into the Controller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't pass in non-DI-managed types into services you want the container to provide for you (in this case, your Tenant parameter). Only request services that the container can provide. If you need a tenant, perhaps another service like an ITenantAccessor could be injected and would be able to get one.

I suspect your implementation could be done in middleware (if not using MVC) or as a filter (if using MVC). In either case, you can use DI from the filter or middleware class to inject your tenant service. In the class's invoke method, you will have access to the current context and request and should be able to do the things you need to. Remember that `ConfigureServices` runs before the app has started, so there is no context and no request is yet being made.

If you want to see some examples of filters, and especially how to do DI into filters, check out:
https://github.com/ardalis/GettingStartedWithFilters

and

http://ardalis.com/real-world-aspnet-core-mvc-filters

If you want to do it in middleware, then these might help:
https://github.com/ardalis/NotFoundMiddlewareSample

and

http://ardalis.com/using-custom-middleware-to-record-and-fix-404s-in-aspnet-core-apps

Comment: Yeah, I pushed ahead and realized that I am really trying to inject data, not just a service. Since extracting the Tenant will happen so often, I wanted to try and automate it via DI.   I'll check these out these resources and report back as answered if it meets my needs. Thanks, @ssmith!

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that what you are injecting in the `TenantUtility` as a frist parameter is a valid abstraction (though it's probably better to use some interface), but the other one is a value-object. You don't generally inject value objects as they are not abstraction of some operations that you need to perform, but data. So I would pass the `Tenant` as a parameter to an operation on the `TenantUtility` class.

Another thing that I can suggest is to use a full-blown DI container like `SimpleInjector` (there are many others like `Ninject`, `CastlWindsor`, etc.). They are much more advanced as far as I know and can easily be integrated. Many of them have `.Net Core` integration already.